# Snap-ins to create Person Account instead of contact

Tags: community, liveagent, person-accounts, snap-ins

I want to use snap-ins but as a chat service. But instead of creating a contact, I want to create and find a Person Account based on the PersonEmail field.
Is this something possible?

I have tried passing the doing this in the snap-ins generated code.

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
          "label": "Record Type ID",
          "value": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "displayToAgent": false
        }];

        embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
          "entityFieldMaps": [{
            "doCreate": true,
            "doFind": true,
            "fieldName": "PersonEmail",
            "isExactMatch": true,
            "label": "Email"
          }, {
            "doCreate": false,
            "doFind": false,
            "fieldName": "LastName",
            "isExactMatch": false,
            "label": "Last Name"
          },
          {
            "doCreate": false,
            "doFind": false,
            "fieldName": "FirstName",
            "isExactMatch": false,
            "label": "First Name"
          },
          {
            "doCreate": false,
            "doFind": false,
            "fieldName": "RecordTypeId",
            "isExactMatch": false,
            "label": "Record Type ID"
          }],
          "entityName": "Account"
        }];
```

Thanks!